# Find a power series centered at the origin that satisfies the Bessel

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Find a power series centered at the origin that satisfies the Bessel differential equation $$zf''(z)+f'(z)+zf(z)=0$$ with initial condition $f(0)=1$. Show that this series converges for all z in C.

I have worked with Diff EQs before I am unsure how to work in the power series.

Comment: Maybe try solving the ODE using the [Frobenius method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method).

Comment: Write $f$ as a power series and plug into the equation. Then by identification $(k+1)kf_{k+1}+(k+1)f_{k+1}+f_{k-1}=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace $f$ with a power series $$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} a_k z^k .$$ Differentiating the series w.r.t. $z$ gives $$f' \sim \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} k a_k z^{k - 1} = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} (k + 1) a_{k + 1} z^k,$$ and one can similarly produce the series for $f''$. Now, substitute these series in the Bessel equation and compare like coefficients to derive a recurrence relation among the coefficients $a_k$.